# Prompting to accept an answer

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

In SO, if you don't accept an answer after a few days, then the following phrase appears above the question:

> Have you considered accepting an
>   answer or starting a bounty for this
>   question?

Is this implement in this site?

Comment: better ask on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; I've seen it for some of the question's I've asked.

Comment: I wonder why it didn't come up for my questions.

Comment: I see it when I click on my handle - down at the bottom; it only shows up after the question goes a several days without an accepted.